# What are the proper conditions and watering habits for rosemary?

Tags: herbs, sowing, rosemary, optimal-conditions

I have tried twice now to start Rosemary from seed and failed both times. Last year I planted them in a self watering window box with a number of other herbs. It never really came up well and never thrived, then we went on vacation and it died.

This year I tried again in a different pot and it still came up slowly or not at all (most seeds did not germinate it seems). Then I knocked the pot over and that was the end of that attempt.

I am ready to try again. I am going to use a 6" self watering container and potting mix and a new pack of seeds.

What are the pitfalls and hangups starting rosemary from seed? What can I do to improve my chances or even ensure success?

My weather: Hot during the summer (mid 90s during the day mid 70s at night). Some rain.

Comment: Your weather also matters, how is your weather?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think one issue with some herbs is that they don't want to be too wet; I'm not sure you want the self-watering container. I let mine dry out a bit before watering it. And they germinate and grow very slowly. I think I soaked mine overnight before putting seed in soil. The germination rate is *very* low.

Some info taken from [this page](http://www.cookingvegetarian.com/herbs/herbs-rosemary.htm):

> - Darkness will aid germination.
> - Cover seeds lightly after sowing.
> - Optimum soil temperature for germination is 60
>     degrees.
> - Germination time 14-21 days.
> - Sow heavily because the seeds have a poor germination rate.
> - Some seeds can germinate up to 3 months after sowing.
> - Water in between dry downs; do not use enclosed planters...

You may find it easier to buy a small plant and then propagate from cuttings.

Comment: yeah, if I fail this time I am definitely going to buy a plant

Answer (score 2):

When I was handling seed propagation at a commercial greenhouse, the seeds were handed to me from the freezer.  I'm sure they would go for 2-4 days.
A whack of seeds in a 6" container may work and I would try a backup bunch in as small a cell as you could keep wet with daily misting. Transfer to bigger and bigger pots up to 6" then to the garden or well drained window box.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried growing from seed, but have managed to clone a cutting in a wet environment i.e. a LECA grow bed in my aquaponics setup. It did take several months to root, and then I was able to transplant into a pot which I gave away - for it to be then killed by over watering by the recipient :(